# How to freeze display so that data can be read by the user?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Does someone knows how I fix for undetermined time the frame that shows the result of this code in progress ? Anytime I run this it appears with the results and disappears at the same way.

```
 FOR EACH tablename no-lock:
    DISPLAY tablename.attribute
            tablename.attribute2.
 END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a PAUSE statement.

The code that you are actually showing should work fine out of the box.  As written tt will display the two fields and and move to the next line.  When the frame has been filled with lines it will automatically PAUSE.

If it is not doing so that would be because there is other code that is not shown.  (Which might be in a procedure that runs this procedure.)

That other code might just be:

```
pause 0 before-hide.
```

Or it might be something more complex such as a frame definition outside the loop.  Like this (using the famous "sports" database):

```
form customer.custNum customer.name skip with frame a.

for each customer no-lock:

  display custNum name with frame a.

end.
```

Adding a PAUSE statement is a quick fix.  Other approaches might be more suitable, for instance:

```
form customer.custNum customer.name skip with frame a 5 down.

for each customer no-lock:

  display custNum name with frame a.
  down with frame a.
end.
```

But whether that is what you need or not depends on what is actually happening in your code and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My original response was written on my cellphone -- I've updated it to be more detailed and, hopefully, more helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much, i already tested it, and it works fine. Btw, can I program a procedure to run everyday at a specific hour ?

Comment: You should post that as a new question.